# Android Lollipop BLE Peripheral: calling BluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(AdvertiseCallback) disconnects from connected central

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads

I wish to stop advertising when a central connects (and subscribes to a specific characteristic):

```
private final BluetoothGattServerCallback bleCallbacks = new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value){
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onDescriptorWriteRequest()...");

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = descriptor.getCharacteristic();
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "----- characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());

        if (characteristic.equals(peripheralCharacteristic)){
            descriptor.setValue(value);
            if (bluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(device,
                    requestId,
                    BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS,
                    offset,
                    value)){
                central = device;
                stopAdvertising(); //causes disconnection
                return;
            }
        }

        bluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(device,
                requestId,
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED,
                0,
                null);
    }
...
}

private void stopAdvertising(){
    if (bluetoothLeAdvertiser != null) {
        bluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(advertiseCallback);
    }
}
```

Upon calling stopAdvertising(), the central and peripheral disconnect
from logcat:

> 04-01 11:26:06.179    7068-7085/package.Class﹕ onDescriptorWriteRequest()...
>
> 04-01 11:26:06.179    7068-7085/package.Class﹕ ----- characteristic: 80a1a1a5-8b5b-e88b-9d24-2e609654b852
>
> 04-01 11:26:06.207    7068-7085/package D/BluetoothGattServer﹕ onServerConnectionState() - status=0 serverIf=5 device=00:07:80:2F:0F:A2

With stopAdvertising() commented, connection (and communication) with the central continues.

Has anyone encountered this issue with Android's BLE Peripheral Implementation? In iOS, there is no such issue.

Comment: if you add more logs, it will be helpful to solve issue. Also is it 5.0 or 5.1/5.01?

Comment: I have the same problem on Nexus 6 with both Android 5.1.1 and 6.0.1 as a peripheral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to call `stopAdvertising` after entering a connection.

The Link Layer from the LE Controller has 5 states: "Idle", "Advertising", "Scanning", "Initiating" and "Connected".

When you advertise, you're in "Advertising" state. When it connects, it goes into "Connected" state.

Most likely, the `stopAdvertising` method assumes you are in "Advertising" state at the time of calling and, without checking this, does what it's supposed to do when you call it in "Advertising": it goes to "Idle" state.

So when you call it, the LL goes into "Idle" regardless of current state.

This seems like a bug in the BLE Host Stack from Android. The correct behaviour when you call `stopAdvertising` in a "Connected" state should be to return an error code (e.g. "Invalid state for this command") or simply ignore.

Comment: Please look into it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184446/bluetooth-le-peripheral-stop-advertising-on-connect-with-bluetooth-le-central-de

Comment: I still get this behaviour in 7.0. Connected peripheral disconnects after I call stopAdvertising. This is very inconvenient for us because our app only expects 1 connection but if we cant stop advertising more connections can come in.

Answer (score 0):

Bogdan's answer applies to Bluetooth LE 4.0. However 4.1 peripherals can connect to more than 1 central, so it makes sense for a peripheral to decide whether or not it wants to stop advertising once a connection is made without immediately losing that connection. This looks like a bug in Android L as recently as 5.1.1