# At what point should BLE advertising be stopped?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have heard that it is a good practice for the peripheral to stop advertising when it is not expecting new connections any more, to save battery.

So, on my peripheral inside `onConnectionStateChange` I call `advertiser.stopAdvertising(advertiseCallback)` like this:

```
 private final BluetoothGattServerCallback bluetoothServerCallback = new BluetoothGattServerCallback()  {

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onConnectionStateChange status=%d, newState=%d", status, newState));
        super.onConnectionStateChange(device, status, newState);

        // advertiser should be turned off when connection state changes
        // but the problem is - this breaks the client side service discovery
        // so, I'm not sure what would be the right moment to stop advertising

        advertiser.stopAdvertising(advertiseCallback);
    }
```

On the client side right after I connect and receive `onConnectionStateChange` with `BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED`, I call

```
 connectedPeripheralGatt.discoverServices()
```

and wait for `onServicesDiscovered` callback.

The problem is that if the peripheral has stopped advertising, `onServicesDiscovered` receives status code 257 (which is a constant for generic vague GATT_FAILURE) and does not discover any services.

If I comment out the `stopAdvertising`, the client side `onServicesDiscovered` works as expected, but then the peripheral continues advertising, although I don't need it any more.

**How then it should work? How do I stop advertising when it is no longer needed?**

Both devices are not paired/bonded. I'm not sure yet what will happen with paired devices - maybe `onServicesDiscovered` would work even when advertising is stopped because of real MAC addresses, but I want to get it working without pairing first.

Comment: After you have made a connection it is no longer advertising... the state should change to `connected`. Once connected the services can be discovered.

Comment: @DigitalNinja I'm not sure if that's true. I just tried establishing a connection between two Android devices, and after it succeeded I immediately ran a BLE scanner on a third device (iPhone) and it immediately detected my peripheral on Android and displayed its services. So, it seems that advertising does not stop automatically after connection. Also, after I disconnected both devices I called `startAdvertising` and immediately got failure ADVERTISE_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED. This means that Android resumed advertising itself after the disconnect or it hadn't stopped advertising at all.

Comment: on client(mobile) stop it before sending connect command.

Comment: @JustAMartin Apologies, I misunderstood. It appears that the Android peripheral does allow for continued advertisements. I'm just so used to embedded Bluetooth modules that I jumped to a conclusion. If you want to stop advertising after a connection (so that other clients cannot see your peripheral) then I think all you need to do is call `stopAdvertising`.

Comment: I wanted to help you because I have done quite a bit of development with BLE but apparently I haven't had enough coffee... stopping advertisements shouldn't cause a GATT failure. Can you show the code where you are calling `advertiser.stopAdvertising(advertiseCallback)`?

Comment: @DigitalNinja - the problem is, as I described, that if I call `onServicesDiscovered` right inside the connection callback on the peripheral, the client fails to retrieve services. It somehow seems that advertising should be kept running while the client is retrieving service data, but the peripheral has no idea when the client will complete service & characteristic discovery.

Comment: @AAnkit - It won't work for the same reason I described - the client fails with error when trying to read service and characteristic UUIDs. Also, I cannot stop advertising on the client side because the peripheral is the one doing advertisements.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184446/bluetooth-le-peripheral-stop-advertising-on-connect-with-bluetooth-le-central-de

Comment: @DigitalNinja - Thanks, it might help, although it is somewhat counter intuitive and hacky - why to connect again if the client has just connected...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, it almost seems like an oversight on Google's part, but `BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED` doesn't mean what you'd think it should. I guess the profile is in a connected state but you aren't actually connected to the GATT server until you call connect on the `BluetoothGattServer` object.

Comment: totally agree with @DigitalNinja.

Comment: I tried that trick - it works for a few times but then at some point it starts throwing GATT_FAILURE again on the client side in `onServicesDiscovered`, although the server side thinks that everything is fine. I will investigate if keeping advertiser running all time will help.